# How to replace a string with values from columns in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, string, replace

I have a table like the following

```
Exp                                Major       Start
---------------------------------- ----------- -------
My names ar W.Major and W.Start    Hal         Bark
W.Major is a doctor                Mark        Slope
```

I want to write a SQL query to replace W.Major or W.start in the `exp` column with the values in the columns `Major` and `Start`.

Can someone please suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: Mind using commas or putting that in some kind of readable tabular format. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd be happy to help if I did.

Comment: What database did you use?

Comment: Exp                                 Major       Start
__________________________________________________________
                                   |        |
'My names are W.Major and W.Start' |  Hal   |      Bark
___________________________________|________|_________________
'W.Major is a doctor'              |  Mark  |      Slope
___________________________________|________|_______________


Sorry guys the above might make more sense? the text in the Exp column I want to replace.
Wherever it shows W.Major I want to replace with the value in the Major column. Same thing for W.start

Answer (score 0):

The key is using two `replace` functions.

```
Update tablename
   set exp = replace (replace (exp, 'W.Major', major), 'W.Start', start);
```

Read more about [replace on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx). This function is more or less the same across all major RDBMSes.

**EDIT:**

In a scenario where you don't know how many keywords and replacement columns are there in your text, I'd suggest you create a stored procedure in which you do the following:

1. Use a temporary table that has two columns- one for the search key, e.g. `'W.Major'`, and the other with the name of the column , e.g. `'major'`. Note that you don't have to store the values from that column, just the name of the column. Like this:-

   ```
   key        replacement_col
   ---------- -----------------
   W.Major    major
   W.Start    start
   ... and so on.
   ```
2. Now build a dynamic SQL looping in with your main table and this temporary table. Loop the way you find comfortable. I would suggest the following method of looping:

   a) From the first row to the last row in your main table, select the column `exp`.

   b) Loop through this value of `exp` to search for any search keywords. Look for the keywords and values in your temp table.

   c) Prepare a dynamic SQL statement which would then write an update query with nested `replace` calls for you. Execute this dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hey Rachcha, suppose I had 50 such columns and in my text I had correspondingly 50 type of W.[] ; do u know how I could then accomplish this?

Comment: Simple - use 50 `replace`s. You have already introduced a lot of complexity here. Or else, use the business layer to do this. Put the keywords and their replacement values into hash tables and iterate through them. That

Comment: Hey thanks Rachcha , is there anything possible that avoids hard coding like that. Say I don't know all the columns beforehand, is there something like a dynamic query that would help resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps you can use a stored procedure. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Edited. I have just added sort of an algorithm instead of the actual code. I can just provide you with an idea right now. Cheers!